# When someone clicks a link in an iframe, navigate the entire window

Tags: html, iframe

This seems to be the opposite of a common question, which implies that maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I have a little app that displays some other page (from a different domain) inside an iframe, with my header on top.  So far, so good.  But when someone clicks a link on that inner page, it just navigates the iframe - I want it to navigate the *entire* page instead (including, and especially, updating the URL in the URL bar).

This is basically the opposite of clickjacking.  I just want the navigation to work as if it weren't an iframe.  Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 10):

The content in the iframe can modify the link's target: use _parent or _top.

```
<a href='#aboutus' target='_parent'>About Us</a>
```

Comment: This sounds good but what if I don't want to modify the iframe contents, and instead want to control this behavior from the outside?

Answer (score 4):

If the contents of the `<iframe>` are in a different domain you can't do it due to security reasons.
If you have access to the other domain and html code you could do something like this on the link:

```
href="javascript:parent.window.location.href='http:/google.com'
```

Comment: this method might cause the iframe to display a textual message with the link href. The better answer was target='_parent'

Comment: Downvoted in preference of the non-script-based solution; i.e. use of naturally provided feature of anchors having targets.  (Notably: for sensible accessibility, indexability, …)

Answer (score 0):

This violates the same-domain origin policy if you don't control both the site inside and outside the `iframe`.

Imagine you put a user's bank inside the `iframe`. If you could register event handlers for things inside the frame (from outside), you could record the user's bank account number, watch the things they click for advertising purposes, misdirect them when they go to take certain actions you don't like... And the frame would show up as being a secured connection to their bank!

If it's your site inside the frame, it's possible, via handing the state through the server, or with the new(ish) [HTML5 Web Messaging](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/) standard, or by manipulating `parent.window` from inside the frame.

Comment: I understand that I can't do quite a lot of things for security reasons, but it seems really mysterious to only allow "frame busting" if the inner site explicitly requests it.

Comment: @apenwarr It's easy to get a user to visit a malicious site. You don't want the malicious site to be able to "drive" an innocent third-party web page - that's a form of XSS.

Comment: I'm not trying to drive anything - I literally just want *my* page to go away.  If I can load a potentially-malicious page in an iframe, it's no more dangerous for that page to be the root page instead of a nested one.

Comment: Why don't you just link to the other page? Boom! Problem solved.